# using c files in gtkmm project

Tags: gtk, gtkmm

I have added c files to gtkmm project target, but since it is c file it cannot make object for it.

So what should i do so that it can be integrated into my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a linking error? Or any error message you can share with us?

Have a look at http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/mixing-c-and-cpp.html

Are you using a C++ compiler for all files? Or are you compiling c and c++ files with different compilers?

If everything else fails, changing the extensions of c files to cpp is worth a try.